# Trying to use an Arduino Uno together with an ISM330DLC communicating through SPI

Tags: arduino-uno, spi

I am trying to get a MEMS-module (ISM330DLC) to work together with an Arduino Uno but I can't get it to work. I am using the ism330dlc drivers.

ISM330dlc Drivers: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STMems_Standard_C_drivers/tree/master/ism330dlc_STdC

ISM330dlc Datasheet: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2339632.pdf

ISM330dlc Application Notes: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/68/eb/a3/cd/2c/78/45/41/DM00468454/files/DM00468454.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00468454.pdf

I have switched out the voltage regulator to a 3.3V on the Arduino following this guide: https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/3-3v-conversion

I am using the STEVAL-MKI182V2 board for easier wiring.
This is the current wiring:

Arduino Pin<------------->STEVAL Pin

Pin 10 (SS)<------------->CS

Pin 11 (MOSI)<------------->SDA

Pin 12 (MISO)<------------->SDO

Pin 13 (SCK)<------------->SCL

SDx is connected to ground, SCx is connected to VddIO. The board is also connected to ground on the Arduino as well as <s>Vin</s> 3.3V.

Here is the code:

```
/* SPI Pin config (There are other pins dedicated to SPI I think) */
#define SSpin 10
#define MOSIpin 11
#define MISOpin 12
#define SCKpin 13

/* Variables used to store data */
static axis3bit16_t data_raw_acceleration;
static axis3bit16_t data_raw_angular_rate;
static float acceleration_mg[3];
static float angular_rate_mdps[3];

static int32_t platform_write(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t *Bufp, uint16_t len) {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite(SSpin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(Reg);
  SPI.transfer(Bufp);
  digitalWrite(SSpin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  return 0;
}
static int32_t platform_read(void *handle, uint8_t Reg, uint8_t     *Bufp, uint16_t len) {
  Reg |= 0x80; //Set bit 0 (MSB) in order to read
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3));
  digitalWrite(SSpin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(Reg);
  *Bufp = SPI.transfer(0x00); //Dummy send to get value from module
  digitalWrite(SSpin, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
  return 0;
}

/* Init mems driver interface */
ism330dlc_ctx_t dev_ctx = {platform_write, platform_read, 0};
//dev_ctx.write_reg = platform_write;
//dev_ctx.read_reg = platform_read;
//dev_ctx.handle = 0; //No handler needed

void setup() {
  delay(100);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SSpin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SSpin, HIGH);

  /* Initialize SPI */
  SPI.begin();
  //SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));     //MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE3


  /* Needed for setup */
  static uint8_t whoamI, rst;

  /* Check if device ID is correct */
  whoamI = 0;
  ism330dlc_device_id_get(&dev_ctx, &whoamI);
  while (whoamI != ISM330DLC_ID) {
    Serial.print("Wrong device ID!! \n"); Serial.print("whoamI: ");     Serial.print(whoamI); Serial.print("\n\n"); delay(50);     ism330dlc_device_id_get(&dev_ctx, &whoamI);
  }

  /*Restore default config */
  ism330dlc_reset_set(&dev_ctx, PROPERTY_ENABLE);
  do {
    Serial.print("reset:"); Serial.print(rst); Serial.print("\n\n");
    ism330dlc_reset_get(&dev_ctx, &rst);
  } while (rst);
```

The problem is that whenever I run this code I get DeviceID 255 no matter what (ism330dlc device id is 106). One thing I noticed is that if I reset the Arduino and quickly insert the USB cable and upload the code (in the time interval of a second) I can get the right device ID, but then I can't restore the default configuration (i.e not read or write again). Any tips what might cause this? I have tried SPI.setClockDivider() as well as different SPI Modes.

UPDATE: Removing ground from GND, SCx and SDx makes me get the correct deviceID but I still get stuck on trying to restore default configurations.

Comment: You are powering the STEVAL board from the VIN pin of the Arduino, while powering the Arduino through USB?

Comment: No sorry about that, I am powering the STEVAL-board using the 3.3v output on the Arduino. Edit: I have also tried powering it using an extern source at 2.8V.

Comment: Sorry there was a time limit on editing comments more than once. The Arduino is powered through USB and the STEVAL board is powered through the 3.3v output.

Comment: I realize now that I have not added any coupling capacitors to Vdd and Vdd_IO, could that affect the data?

Comment: Unlikely. The STEVAL board will have plenty of decoupling built in.

Comment: When I measure the CS pin it alternates between 2.4V and 2.6V when doing reads, is the difference too small? Vdd_IO is at 3.25V (same as Vdd).
SDO (MISO) is always 3.15V, SDA (MOSI) is switching between 0.3V and 1.3V, SCK is always 3.25. These values doesn't seem to be correct, right?